# Npgsql 6.x: How to find type mapping for CLR Type

Tags: c#, .net, npgsql

In one of my projects I'm migrating Npgsql from 5.x to 6.x and I noticed that Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper is missing Mapping property.

In 5.x I was using this property to find CLR type and get it's mapping to Postgres Type Name (PgTypeName).
Now (in 6.x), when Mappings property is gone, I need to do it in other way. So, how it is possible in Npgsql 6.x to map CLR Type to Postgres Type Name?

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate an NpgsqlParameter, set its value to something, and then check its DataTypeName property.

Comment: Thanks. Good try, but it does not work for nullable types. I'm using reflection to get the CLR type and it's value. However I solved my issue with NpgsqlParameter and checking underlying type (if property DataTypeName returns null) and create default value for the type. It's enough to complete my requirements. Approach in 5.x with GlobalTypeMapper were more straighforward.

Comment: I did some work in https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/pull/4341 which should fix the nullable issue. In the meantime, you can simply always unwrap the nullable (with Nullable.GetUnderlyingType) before setting the value.

Comment: GlobalTypeMapper was a very Npgsql-specific API, which was meant to be used by type mapping plugins rather than for this kind of thing. It seems better to just use standard, public APIs rather than that mechanism.